# Как сделать похожее сообщение об ошибке в Discord?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сделать похожую ошибку для своего в discord.py?

Хочу вывести "системное" сообщение

Comment: Расскажите, на каком этапе вы остановились, покажите ваш код, что именно у вас не получается? [Как задать вопрос хороший вопрос на StackOverflow?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Вот код:

```py
try:
    ... #код
except Exception as e: 
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", description=e, color=0xFF5733)
```